# How does Pandas groupby cumsum work differently from groupby sum?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have a dataset where there may be multiple subscriptions under a single Project Code, similar to the one created below:

```
data = {'Project Code': [1622, 1622,1622,1622,1622,1622,1622,1622],
'Subscription Line': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1]
'Date': [4/1/2020, 4/1/2020, 5/1/2020, 5/1/2020, 6/1/2020, 6/1/2020, 7/1/2020, 8/1/2020],
'Subscription Spend': [ 293, 195, 31, 200, 0, 0, 3270,184],
'Projected Subscription Spend': [11758, 8970, 12261, 6807, 9963, 5480, 11885, 9900],
'Project-Month':['1622April2020', ' 1622April2020', '1622May2020', '1622May2020', '1622June2020', '1622June2020', '1622July2020', '1622August2020']
}
df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Project Code', 'Date', 'Subscription Spend', 'Projected Subscription Spend', 'Project-Month'])
```

I want to calculate a column which calculates the Project-level Projected Spend as the sum of the 'Projected Subscription Spend'. So for April 2020 the Projected Project Spend would be 11,758 + 8,970 = 20,728, and this would be shown for both rows. So the Projected Project Spend would look like this:

```
'Projected Project Spend' = [20728, 20728, 19068, 19068, 15443, 15443, 11885, 9900]
```

I have tried to do this using groupby and sum, but when I ran the code I got blanks in 'Projected Project Spend'. However when I used cumsum I got values that function in the way you would expect cumsum to- they add up over time. The two lines of code I tried are below:

```
df['Projected Project Spend'] = (df['Subscription Spend']).groupby(df['Subscription Code']).sum()
df['Projected Project Spend'] = (df['Projected Subscription Spend']).groupby(df['Project-Month']).cumsum()
```

Why would sum have null output when cumsum doesn't? How can I make sum work?

Comment: You may want to try `.transform(sum)`

Comment: HI @Amie. I have tried out the solution. I think it works as you wanted it to work. see below my answer. let me know if it worked for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Similar to what commented by Chris, but with `'sum'` for better performance:

```
df['Total_Spend'] = (df.groupby(['Project Code', 'Date'])
                        ['Projected Subscription Spend'].transform('sum')
                    )
```

Output:

```
      Project Code  Date        Subscription Spend    Projected Subscription Spend  Project-Month      Total_Spend
--  --------------  --------  --------------------  ------------------------------  ---------------  -------------
 0            1622  4/1/2020                   293                           11758  1622April2020            20728
 1            1622  4/1/2020                   195                            8970  1622April2020            20728
 2            1622  5/1/2020                    31                           12261  1622May2020              19068
 3            1622  5/1/2020                   200                            6807  1622May2020              19068
 4            1622  6/1/2020                     0                            9963  1622June2020             15443
 5            1622  6/1/2020                     0                            5480  1622June2020             15443
 6            1622  7/1/2020                  3270                           11885  1622July2020             11885
 7            1622  8/1/2020                   184                            9900  1622August2020            9900
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
data = {'Project Code': [1622, 1622,1622,1622,1622,1622,1622,1622],
'Subscription Line': [1,2,1,2,1,2,1,1],
'Date': [4/1/2020, 4/1/2020, 5/1/2020, 5/1/2020, 6/1/2020, 6/1/2020, 7/1/2020, 8/1/2020],
'Subscription Spend': [ 293, 195, 31, 200, 0, 0, 3270,184],
'Projected Subscription Spend': [11758, 8970, 12261, 6807, 9963, 5480, 11885, 9900],
'Project-Month':['1622April2020', ' 1622April2020', '1622May2020', '1622May2020', '1622June2020', '1622June2020', '1622July2020', '1622August2020']
}

df = pd.DataFrame (data, columns = ['Project Code', 'Date', 'Subscription Spend', 'Projected Subscription Spend', 'Project-Month'])

df['month']=df['Project-Month'].str[4:-4] #create a new column for month
df.iloc[1,-1]='April' # second row was reading 2April so corrected it
df.groupby(['month'],axis=0).sum()['Projected Subscription Spend']
```

the `groupby` perhaps on project-Month is not working as the second row has some misformat which I corrected.